# Why UDP socket is not working when stored as class member in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, datagram

I am new to `UDP/datagram` package in Node, please pardon me if wrong in my conceptual understanding here.

I tried creating an abstract class **UdpClient** using NodeJS `dgram` package

**Code is in TypeScript**

```js
import { deserialize, serialize } from "v8"

type ClientInfo = {
    address: string,
    port: number
}

type Message = {
    messageUuid: string,
    type: string,
    body: any
}

class UdpClient {
    socket: Socket
    constructor(onMessage: (message: Message) => any) {
        this.socket = createSocket("udp4")
        this.socket.on("message", (msg) => {
            const message = deserialize(msg)
            onMessage(message)
        })
        this.socket.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log({ err });
        })
    }
    send = (rinfo: ClientInfo, message: Message) => () => {
        console.log(this.socket.ref.toString());
        this.socket.on('error', (err)=>{
            console.log("err", err);
        })
        this.socket.send(
            serialize(message),
            rinfo.port,
            rinfo.address,
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Implementation of the above class

```js
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid"
const serverInfo = {
        port: 65530,
        address: "127.0.0.1"
    }
const alice = new UdpClient((message)=>{
   console.log("Alice:", message);
})
alice.send(serverInfo, {
   type: 'ping',
   messageUuid: uuid(),
   body: null
})
```

Result of Above code:-

- No message received by Server
- No error displayed here

```js
        this.socket.on('error', (err)=>{
            console.log("err", err);
        })
```

**Whereas** if I try simple flow by creating UDP socket object and use it directly as examples here [Node JS docs UDP/Datagram](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/dgram.html)

```js
const serverInfo = {
        port: 65530,
        address: "127.0.0.1"
    }
const alice = createSocket('udp4')
const message = {
   type: 'ping',
   messageUuid: uuid(),
   body: null
}
alice.send(
    serialize(message),
    serverInfo.port,
    serverInfo.address
)
```

Result of Above code:-

- Message is received by the server

**What could be the issue with storing the socket as member of my `UdpClient` class?**

- It has something to do with TS compiler creating function type classes?
- Something wrong in my code?
- Or some intrinsic property of socket object made with `createSocket` function?

And if my approach is wrong, please suggest the right way to do it.

Comment: Having the same issue in 2023, seems to work just fine when the socket is not a class member. Did you ever solve this?